# How to use localstorage value in ngif

Tags: angular

I need to use localstorage value in `ngif`..

How can I do it.. I tried various methods but cannot get..

Below is my code attached

```
<ng-template *ngIf="readLocalStorageValue('Role')== 'admin'">

    <button 
        class="btn btn-primary editable-table-button btn-xs"
       (click)="updatetq(tq_list.cmslearntopicid, tq_list.cmslearnchapterid,tq_list.topicname);"
    >Edit</button>

    <button 
        class="btn btn-danger editable-table-button btn-xs"
        (click)="deletet(tq_list.cmslearntopicid);"
    >Delete</button>

</ng-template>
```

Also below is ts file as well:
When i print value then its showing admin but then also it is not working...

Need help.. Can someone help me

```
readLocalStorageValue(key) {
  let value =   localStorage.getItem(key);
  console.log("-------"+value);

  if(value == undefined) {
    value =='';
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: just use `if(typeof value == 'undefined')` instead of `if(value == undefined)`

Comment: If you already have a [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) `#someElem` lying around, a quick hack would be to `someElem?.innerElement?.nativeElement?.ownerDocument.defaultView.localStorage['your-key']` (`?` for safety) - no changes to component classes; handy for doing stuff along the lines of `*ngIf="localStorage['experimental']"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your `readLocalStorageValue(key)` is overly complicated.

You can just use:

```
readLocalStorageValue(key) {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
}
```

Second, don't use functions in templates if you don't have to, because Angular change detection will cause them to execute multiple times. You probably saw it already, when your console log was printed multiple times. So you should store the result of `readLocalStorageValue` method in a variable like `role` and use the variable in place of a method in your template with `*ngIf`

More on that topic here https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16

Third.
You are using `ng-template` when you should be using `ng-container`. With `ng-template` tag you define a template, but you don't use it, so nothing gets rendered. What you want to be using with `*ngIf` is `ng-container`

I know it's confusing, so better check this post https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Your component code should be:

```
role: string;

ngOnInit(){
    this.role = this.readLocalStorageValue('Role');
}

readLocalStorageValue(key: string): string {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
}
```

Your template code should be:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="role==='admin'">

     <button class="btn btn-primary editable-table-button btn-xs" (click)="updatetq(tq_list.cmslearntopicid
                  ,tq_list.cmslearnchapterid,tq_list.topicname);">Edit</button>

     <button class="btn btn-danger editable-table-button btn-xs" (click)="deletet(tq_list.cmslearntopicid);">Delete</button>

</ng-container>
```

Comment: Might want to re-read that article as the author clearly states: `So is it a good practice to call methods in the views? I would say no but I’m not an Angular 2 expert (I only work with Angular 2 since the January of 2016)` In a lot of cases with localStorage you probably want your state as soon as possible, otherwise you would just use a life cycle hook to begin with.

Comment: Method are okay, as long as you know what your doing. It's also such a micro-optimization for the most part as at most you'll get 3-4 calls, unless your doing something wrong. Furthermore with your variable you won't get updates from the variable changing either way without other mechanisms.

Comment: @li - This statement by the author is ambiguous, because he also states that it's ok to run methods in templates, if they are simple. mehul wants to query local storage in his `readLocalStorageValue()` method. Hypothetically, he could have a lot of items stored in local storage, so this function would be more expensive to run.

Comment: @mehul - my mistake. Should be `<ng-container *ngIf="role==='admin'">` Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do *`ngIf='localStorage.getItem(key) === "admin"'` from directly inside your `ngIf` as it'll do the same validation as your current `readLocalStorageValue()` method as well as changing when the localStorage updates.

Alternatively you could use a service and a `behavior subject` that you pass into your components state via injection.

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {

    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    notifyLocalComponents(message: string) {
        this.subject.next({text: message});
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }

}
```

The above service is where you'd build your logic to update the localStorage values in the behaviour subject. Then you can subscribe to changes like this:

```
    constructor(private storageService: LocalStorageService){
       this.storageService.getMessage().subscribe(()=>{ // Update local state here when an update has been found. });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach and also I would suggest using the observables to keep listening changes for the localstorage

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zggcza)

Note: In the Demo, I have added the line `localStorage.setItem('role', "admin");` in the ngOnInit to add the role as admin manually and you can verify that div element shows only when the role is set to admin otherwise it doesn't appear

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  checkStatus: boolean;

  public localStorageItem(): boolean {
    if (localStorage.getItem("role") === "admin") {
      return true
    } else {
      return false;
    };
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkStatus = this.localStorageItem();
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="checkStatus">
  .
  .
<div>
```